# MacMini goes into password recovery mode after power outage when mouse and keyboard are not connected

Tags: startup, mac-mini, peripheral

I have a Apple MacMini (2018 3GHz 6-core Intel Core i5, 16GB) and I run it as a server with some Docker containers (Home Assistant, Pi-hole, etc).

All works fine, as long as power is on. Power outage are rare here, but if for some reason the MacMini loses power (group test, accidental press on power-splitter button etc) and Im not home (I travel frequently) I have to ask someone at home to reset it.

But then comes the issue; it powers on again after power outage, but then because it doesn't have a mouse and keyboard connected it goes into password recovery mode and refuses just to boot nicely to the login screen, where I could then remotely access it with VNC and SSH. Also Docker and all other tools start automatically again on boot, so a power outage wouldn't be a big issue, as long as it simply boots into the OS itself.

Is there some way on a firmware level to stop this from happening? It's very annoying, because people at home have little technical knowledge and cant easily perform the tasks. I could buy the cheapest mouse and keyboard so that something is connected and it just boots normal, but I would love to know if there's an alternative.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about if it's set to auto-login? [You could always set a very short time for it to lock again.]

Comment: Are you sure this affects the boot cycle? I could try it, but it doesn't even reach the OS itself. I'll test it in a moment. Thank you for your response!

Comment: I can't test on a modern mini, but I have an old Mac Pro here with all wireless peripherals, & that auto-boots fine. It's set to auto-login & I just wondered if it could possibly make a difference.

Comment: I wanted to test it, but it says it's impossible to do it when FileVault is enabled, which I would like to keep enabled.

Comment: Ah, OK. I never thought of that. I don't use FV here.

Comment: I also noticed that macOS seems to be degrading a lot in it's quality of installation. When I reinstalled it and only used only the keyboard, it's practically impossible. It just demands that you have a mouse and the accessibility tools to use keyboard as a mouse requires you to "click" ‍♂️. Also when using a non-Apple Bluetooth mouse (Logitech 2S) is very difficult, unless you wire it. I feel that this hasn't been tested well and seemed to work a lot better all the 15~20 years before on all older OS X/macOS versions. I guess sometimes we get some and lose some hehe.

Comment: TBH, I'm not sure that's a 'new thing'. I can't boot my 2009 Pro to Recovery from a wireless keyboard, I have to grab one of the wired ones. I haven't thought about running one mouseless.

Comment: When I Google about it I think it's an issue with non-Apple devices. My Apple wireless keyboard works fine pre-OS, but as soon as you want to use other brands it's game over .